# Seeking Geospatial CMS like Cartaro without Internet connection?

Tags: offline, content-management-system

I want to install geospatial CMS like Cartaro and I'm interested in whether this CMS works in an intranet environment without taking data from services such as Openlayers, Google map, etc.

Is there a database (world map) as the demo site http://demo.cartaro.org/  that can be used offline?

Answer (score 1):

You may import many types of geographic data formats into Cartaro and thus make them available without internet connection. The easier way to do so is to import vector data from a Shapefile, KML or WFS. Check the [documentation for the GDAL module in Cartaro](https://drupal.org/node/2133129) to see how it works. You can find many data sources for e.g. [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Shapefiles) in these formats.
Importing raster data is not so straight forward, but you can do it through the GeoServer that comes with Cartaro. Check Geoserver's raster documentation for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could install geonode - http://geonode.org on virtualbox and just access geoserver from your localhost. There's a version of geonode called Geoshape - http://Geoshape.org follow their steps under "How to get geoshape" which uses an automation (vagrant and chef) pre-scripted build to create the instance for you... Set it come back 30min later and go to you localhost and there's your offline geo cms... Only concern is the ram and cpu sharing between virtualbox and your OS; what kind of machine do you have?